# What Type should be used on a React Component that returns a Boolean or JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am using AWS-Ampify to handle my login. Because the user session is an asynchronous process, I would like to prevent the app from changing state when it first loads. To do this, I would like to prevent the app from rendering while my isAuthenticating boolean is still false.

In short, I was hoping to conditionally render the app based on the isAuthenticating flag:

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [isAuthenticating, setIsAuthenticating] = useState(true);
  const [isAuthenticated, userHasAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    onLoad();
  }, []);

  const onLoad = async () => {
    try {
      await Auth.currentSession();
      userHasAuthenticated(true);
    } catch (e) {
      if (e !== "No current user") {
        alert(e);
      }
    }

    setIsAuthenticating(false);
  };
  return (
    !isAuthenticating && (
      <div>
        <AppContext.Provider value={{ isAuthenticated, userHasAuthenticated }}>
          <NavbarElement />
          <Routes />
          <FooterElement />
        </AppContext.Provider>
      </div>
    )
  );
};

export default App;
```

The issue I am running into is Typescript is throwing the following error:

*Type '() => false | JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'FC<{}>'.
Type 'false | Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any> | null'.
Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any> | null'.  TS2322*

Is there a type I can assign the function that will allow it to return either a boolean or some JSX?

Answer (score 3):

The error was caused by the shorthand syntax and not due to the component type. The following resolved the error posted above:

```
return (
    <>
      {!isAuthenticating && (
        <div>
          <AppContext.Provider
            value={{ isAuthenticated, userHasAuthenticated }}
          >
            <NavbarElement />
            <Routes />
            <FooterElement />
          </AppContext.Provider>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: By design, a functional component is supposed to return JSX or `null`. So returning a `boolean` goes against convention. The simple fix would be to turn your conditional into a ternary operation: `!isAuthenticating ? <div>...</div> : null`